# Bringing to front app in background using a notification (emulating same home screen icon behaviour)

Tags: android, android-notifications

I know there are other similar questions, and I've tried them all, WITHOUT success.  That's why I'm posting my code here, in case someone can visualize the proper solution for my case and suggest a specific action in the code,  please help.

I've tried:  Adding some tags to the manifest file in the activity called by the intent, adding flags and actions and categories to the actual intent in the code, creating a dummy activity to be call in the intent with finish(), etc.

Thanks for any suggestion.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
         new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.lampp)))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.lampp));

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Thanks to a combination of the answer posted by @Merlevede and a previous post, this is how it was solved:

Use this code for your Notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
         new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.lampp)))
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.lampp));

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotiActivity.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

And this is the code for the dummy Activity called in the intent NotiActivity.class:

```
public class NotiActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    finish();

} 
  }
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Is there are reason you're using TaskStackBuilder, can you do without?

Comment: Hi Merlevede, I'm using the basic developer example..  that's the only reason... I can do without...   yes..

Comment: By the way, you haven't described your problem. Is it nowt working at all, or is it creating another instance of activity?

Comment: It's launching or restarting the App, as a new instance. What I want to do is to behave as :  You're In App -> Push Home Button ->You're in Home Screen ->Push App Icon->You're in App exactly where you left it, with even the same text you've written without even saving it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might be useful to you. You might be missing some flags on your notification intent, specially take a look at `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

I use a notification for a service using this code.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

There are a few differences with your code. Also I'm using this notification from a service so I'm using `startForeground` to set the notification.

It's worth giving it a try.